# How to make autospace after every 4 digit in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-forms

I'm trying to make credit/debit card form with React. I want to make autoinsert space after every 4 digit and to force the user type numbers only. For example, if input 1234567891234567 it will become with spaces 1234 5678 9123 4567.
The problem is when I press backspace the spaces can't be deleted because I use onChange event. I'm new to React, probably need a different approach. What else I can use to make the backspace working properly and how to forbid writing of letters (digits only)?

```
const [cardNumber, setCardNumber] = useState('')
    const handleChange = async (e) => {

    if (e.target.value.length === 4) {
        e.target.value += ' '
    } else if (e.target.value.length === 9) {
        e.target.value += ' '
    } else if (e.target.value.length === 14) {
        e.target.value += ' '
    }

    setCardNumber(e.target.value)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Id create a state variable to hold the cc-number

```
const [ccNumber, setCcNumber] = useState("");
```

And set the `ccNumber` `onChange` of the input

```
<input type="text" value={ccNumber} onChange={formatAndSetCcNumber} />
```

And inside fn `formatAndSetCcNumber` I'd handle the logic

```
const formatAndSetCcNumber = e => {
    const inputVal = e.target.value.replace(/ /g, ""); //remove all the empty spaces in the input
    let inputNumbersOnly = inputVal.replace(/\D/g, ""); // Get only digits

    if (inputNumbersOnly.length > 16) {
        //If entered value has a length greater than 16 then take only the first 16 digits
        inputNumbersOnly = inputNumbersOnly.substr(0, 16);
    }

   // Get nd array of 4 digits per an element EX: ["4242", "4242", ...]
    const splits = inputNumbersOnly.match(/.{1,4}/g);

    let spacedNumber = "";
    if (splits) {
        spacedNumber = splits.join(" "); // Join all the splits with an empty space
    }

    setCcNumber(spacedNumber); // Set the new CC number
};
```

Here is a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-p3gmb7)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const handleChange = async (e) => {
    setCardNumber(e.target.value)
}

useEffect(()=>{
    if(cardNumber.length===4)
        setcardNumber(cardNumber+" ")
    else if (cardNumber.length === 9) {
        setcardNumber(cardNumber+" ")
    } else if (cardNumber.length === 14) {
        setcardNumber(cardNumber+" ")
    }
}, [cardNumber]);
```

Sorry for any typos.